# Show if $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f$ be defined on a neighborhood of $x_0$. Show $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ if and only if the discontinuity of

$$ h(x) = \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$

at $x_0$ is removable.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to start on this prove. Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) $f$ is differentiable, so the limit $\lim_{x\to x_0} h(x)$ exists, thus the discontinuity at $x_0$ of $h$ is removable.
2) $x_0$ is a removable singularity of $h$, so the limit $\lim_{x\to x_0} h(x)$ exists and thus $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$

Answer (score 1):

The discontinuity of $g$ in $x_0$ is removable iff

$$\lim_{x \to x_0^-} g(x) = \lim_{x \to x_0^+} g(x) = L,$$

with $L$ finite.

The function $f$ is diffentiable in $x_0$ iff (this holds for the mono-dimensional case, that is, $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$)

$$\lim_{x \to x_0^-} g(x) = \lim_{x \to x_0^+} g(x) = L,$$

with $L$ finite.